# Reusable function type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying declare a function type and then use that in a class, and in objects, and interfaces like this:

```
declare function IUpdateMode(mode: Mode): void;
```

Then I want to use it like this:

```
type Foo = {
   updateMode: IUpdateMode
}


class Foo extends React.Component<any> {

    updateRedMode(mode): IUpdateMode {}

}

function updateGreenMode(mode): IUpdateMode {

}
```

Is this possible in typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really want is just this:

```
type UpdateMode = (mode: Mode) => void
```

Now you can use it anywhere as you mentioned, but with some corrections:

```
interface IFoo { // interface instead of a type is preferable when possible (e.g. you may extend it)
   updateMode: UpdateMode
}


class Foo extends React.Component<any> implements IFoo {

    updateMode = (mode: Mode) => {}

}

const updateGreenMode: UpdateMode = (mode) => { // there is no way to restrict a classic function to type alias or interface

}
```

Comment: Oh thank you! Is it not possible to use this with the `function upgradeGreenMod() {}` style?

Comment: You are welcome! No, it's not possible unfortunately, to restrict a classic function to some type alias or interface.

Comment: I've polished the answer a bit more. e.g. the (non-mandatory, for-convenience) convention is to add "I" character to the beginning of interfaces, not types. Also class should implement `Ifoo` interface